# JavaScript memory loss with Prototype's Ajax.Updater?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm not sure this is a Prototype specific issue, but since I don't have the problem when not using Prototype I guess it is.

I'm using Ajax.Updater to append some external HTML to my DOM tree. In the external file there are some script elements. Since I have set the evalScripts options to true, they are all evaluated. But when I later try to access objects that have been set in the script elements, they no longer exists. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = true;
    console.log(test); // Works fine, obviously.
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="console.log(test)"> <!-- Throws an ReferenceError exception (test is not defined) when the event is fired. -->
```

If I request this with Ajax.Updater the script element will run as expected, but after the evaluation the test variable seems to be deleted. Anyone who knows what's going on?

Comment: try `console.log(window.test)` or better yet `window.test = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.test = true; // global on window
    console.log(test); // Works fine, obviously.
</script>
```

Ajax.Updater will eventually call this on your scripts:

```
function evalScripts() {
    return this.extractScripts().map(function(script) { return eval(script) });
}
```

since `eval` works locally you find that `var test` is actually a local variables of `function(script) { ... }`

This is your issue. It's an issue with prototype not doing global evals like jQuery does.

You can either look hard for it or bump this [ticket](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/101-ajax-request-scripts-not-eval-in-the-global-scope).

Comment: Yes, appending to an existing object works, but it's not applicable in my specfic case. Any idea what's causing this problem?

Comment: @user544941 what do you mean its not applicable? If you want a global variable then write it into the window object. That is _the_ way to make globals.

Comment: Of course it's not. You're just adding a variable to the window object. If you use the var keyword in the global namespace, then you're creating a global variable.

Comment: @user544941 there the same thing. In the browser the `[[Global Context]]` resolves to the `Window` object. Every global variable you create becomes a property on the global object. In browser `window === global Object`. In other environments the global object (`global`) does not have dual meaning like `window` does. (Yes it's bad design for browsers)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. What I meant with not applicable is quite difficult to explain, but lets say I work with an old project with tons of code which is requested with Ajax.Updater (this wasn't really my idea) and to set all these variables, functions and objects to the window object will cost a lot of time. And going the other way around won't work (window.test is undefined when firing the onkeydown event). What IS causing this problem?

Comment: @user544941 I figure ajax updater is wrapping it in a closure and does giving private scope

Comment: Ah, that was my first thought too. But for some reason I got the idea that you can't access things outside the private closure (which I could when I tested, so figured it couldn't be a private closure). But you actually can access stuff outside the private closure, of course. Thanks for the help! It seems pretty unnecessary to wrap the code into a private closure, though.

Comment: @user544951 I found the piece of offending code. Prototype does not eval your loaded script in global scope.